# How to load multiple iframes with same src on one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am creating a WordPress based website and I have a web page where there are multiple iframes with the same src.When I load this page all iframes are showing the same result, but every iframe should have different iframe content with the values sent using session(used for sending data from a PHP file to another PHP file) from where iframe is defined to the iframe src.The web page basically contains users of the website giving different reviews.The iframe in the web page is used for displaying star rating given in each user review.So, each iframe is displayed with values(userid,etc.) to display user's star rating and other user related data.

---

An image of a webpage:

[image: Image of webpage]

---

An image of the iframe:

[image: Image of the iframe]

Comment: Your iframes is on the same server than where the session is running?

Comment: The iframe src is created as a template in the wordpress theme folder and iframe is defined in a plugin php file.

Answer (score -1):

Use Ajax instead if it's on the same server.